# Adding extra feature to word2vec embeddings for use in classification

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, word-embeddings, word2vec

I have a word2vec model that will transform my text into vectors, and I need to use them to classify the text. My data is essentially a timeseries of chat messages, so I think that the message frequency(Total messages / total time) holds a lot of information that should be used to classify.

I was thinking of taking the chat stream, combining them all into a single string, and then averaging all the word's word2vec representations together. But I also want the classifier to be able to use the message frequency.

Can I simply append the message frequency value onto the averaged word embedding vector?

Comment: Yes. See https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/compose/plot_column_transformer.html for some inspiration. But perhaps there's a way to take better advantage of the chat time series data?

Comment: Thanks, do you have any recommendations? I’m also planning on trying out doc2vec